# Sql Server 2008 Express Edition Licensing

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I'm deploying a web application into a server (hosting company).
The application uses Sql Server 2008 Express Edition as its database.
It seems from the license agreement that this state is ok, as Microsoft says:

"All editions of SQL Server Express are free downloads that can be redistributed subject to agreement. Each edition can function both as the client database and as a basic server database. Any edition of SQL Server Express is an ideal choice for independent software vendors (ISVs), server users, non-professional developers, Web developers, Web site hosts, and hobbyists who are building client applications... "

I didn't see any explicit reference on that case.
Do you have any experience with that issue?
Is there any license problem with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, no licensing problems at all - SQL Server 2008 Express is **FREE** to use, to deploy, to install - and can be used for any kind of hobbyist or commercial application - no restrictions.

Comment: More interesting, to my company, are the limitations: single CPU, 1GB RAM, 4GB database size, 32-bit only. (Okay, that was 2005. Do these still hold true for 2008?)

Comment: @Michael: yes, those limitations are still the same for the 2008 versions. The FILESTREAM data (e.g. documents) however does **not** count against those 4 GB per database - just in case you're dealing with large numbers of documents :-)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has a new 10 GB database size limit

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx