# SQL Server Multiple Instances License

Tags: sql-server

Since SQL Server Express is free to use, If I install two instances of the same version on a single CPU machine, will there be any licensing issue even though it is free?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server 2008 Express Edition Licensing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320954/sql-server-2008-express-edition-licensing)

Comment: Sorry, I could not get it. Can I install two instances of same SQL Server Express version (2005) without any licensing problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.

I currently have a VM that has:

- SQL Server 2005 Express
- SQL Server 2008 Express
- MySQL 5.1.49 Community
- Oracle Express (10g)

I don't recommend having them all run on start up, unless you actually need to access them.